# TypeError: $.mobile.activePage is undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Hi Friends I am new in jQuery mobile and developing a website using it. I created a function to control the height of the page as per the window height when its working fine but when i jump to anuther page its stop working and giving error

```
TypeError: $.mobile.activePage is undefined
```

I dont know what is the metter need your help to solve this issue

Please help me guys. You can check my code below

**USED LIBRARIES**

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr-2.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var header_height  = $.mobile.activePage.children('[data-role="header"]').height(),
            footer_height  = $.mobile.activePage.children('[data-role="footer"]').height(),
            window_height  = $(this).height(),
            content_height = window_height - header_height - footer_height;

            $.mobile.activePage.children('[data-role="content"]').children('.contentMain').height(content_height-130).css('overflow','auto');

            $('#left-menu').height(window_height).css('overflow','auto');
```

Please help me guys... Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this method. http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-getActivePage

Comment: Have you wrapped your JS code in `$(document).on('pageinit', function() { //code });`?

Comment: no.. I wrapped it in $(document).ready(function(){  // code  //})

Comment: @kamal so it won't work in mobile device if doc ready used with jquery mobile.

Comment: so what to do ... please explain...

Comment: or share any example..

Answer (score 1):

As Jai said,

For jQuery mobile, $(document).ready( ) and device ready are not the same.

It takes more time to jQuery to get loaded than the document.

You should do something like this :

```
$(function() {
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
//for testing in Chrome browser uncomment
//onDeviceReady(); });
```

And

```
    function onDeviceReady() {
                var header_height  = $.mobile.activePage.children('[data-role="header"]').height(),
                footer_height  = $.mobile.activePage.children('[data-role="footer"]').height(),
                window_height  = $(this).height(),
                content_height = window_height - header_height - footer_height;

                $.mobile.activePage.children('[data-role="content"]').children('.contentMain').height(content_height-130).css('overflow','auto');

                $('#left-menu').height(window_height).css('overflow','auto');
}
```

Furthermore, activePage has been deprecated.
you can use

```
$( ".selector" ).pagecontainer( "getActivePage" );
```

source : http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-getActivePage

Answer (score 1):

You can get id & jquery page visited as shown below

```
$(document).live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
        var pageId = "";
        try{
            pageId = $.mobile.activePage.attr('id');  //Get the page id 
        } catch (e) { }
        if (typeof (pageId) == 'undefined' && pageId == "")
            pageId = event.target.id;
```

}